# How do I get the records from the left side of a join that do not exist in the joined table?

Tags: sql, left-join

I have table a joining table b, I only want the records from table a that **do not exist** in table b.

My partial query is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.id, u.lastname
FROM user u
LEFT JOIN context ct
ON ct.userid = u.id
```

thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select distinct u.id,
    u.lastname
from user u
left join context ct on ct.userid = u.id
where ct.userid is null
```

Comment: The only caveat is that you need to use a column that does not take NULL values.  If you don't have one, you can use a subquery, such as (select ct.*, 1 as col from context ct) ct, to get an appropriate column.