# Displaying MySQL rows on a JOIN query even when records do not exist in another table

Tags: php, mysql

I have an PHP/MySQL application which is connected to a database featuring 2 tables called `'displays'` and `'display_substances'`. The structure of these tables is as follows:

```
mysql> DESCRIBE displays;
+----------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type                 | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | smallint(5) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| label    | varchar(255)         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

mysql> DESCRIBE display_substances;
+--------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type                  | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | mediumint(8) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| display_id   | smallint(5) unsigned  | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| substance_id | mediumint(8) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| value        | text                  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

There is also a `'substances'` table and the foreign key `display_substances.substance_id` is associated with `substances.id`.

The `'displays'` table contains exactly 400 rows and the `'display_substances'` approx 1.5 million rows.

What I'm trying to do is output all 400 `'displays.label'` into a HTML table, and then in a second column show the `'display_substances.value'`. Since the page only shows 1 substance at a time it also needs to be based on the `'display_substances.substance_id'`.

The issue I'm having is that records only exist in `'display_substances'` when we have data available for the appropriate `'displays'`. However, the output has to show *all* records from `'displays'` and then put the text "Not Listed" next to anything where there is no corresponding record in `'display_substances'`.

I've done the following - **which gives me the output I want** - but is flawed (see "The Problem" section below).

1. Select all of the records in the "displays" table: `SELECT label FROM displays ORDER BY label ASC`
2. Select all `display_substances.display_id` for the substance currently being shown: `SELECT display_id FROM display_substances WHERE substance_id = 1` (assuming 1 is the current substance ID). Store the ID's in an array called `$display_substances`
3. Loop through (1) and use `in_array()` to see if (2) exists:

   ```
   foreach ($displays as $display) { // step (1)
       $display_substances = // See step (2)
       if (in_array($display['id'], $display_substances)) { // step (3)
           $display_value = // See step (4)
       } else {
           $display_value = 'Not listed';
       }
       $output[] = ['display_label' => $display['label'], 'display_value' => $display_value]; // See step (5)
   }
   ```
4. If the `in_array()` condition is true then I make a query to select the corresponding row of "display_substances": `SELECT value FROM display_substances WHERE display_id = $display['id'] AND substance_id = 1`
5. The `$output` variable buffers all the data and then it gets output into a HTML table later. The output I get is exactly as I want.

### The problem

Although the output is correct I want to do this all as 1 query (if possible) because I need to add features to search by either `displays.label` or `display_substances.value` - or a combination of both. The first part of this is fairly trivial because I can amend the query in (1) to:

```
SELECT label FROM displays WHERE label LIKE '% Foo %' ORDER BY label ASC
```

However, this **won't** make `display_substances.value` searchable because by the time we get to step (3) we're dealing with a single row of `display_substances` not the whole table. I can't see how to write it differently though since we need to know which records exist in that table for the loaded substance.

I have also written the following query - but this **will not** work because it misses anything that's "Not Listed":

```
SELECT displays.label, display_substances.`value` FROM displays JOIN display_substances ON displays.id = display_substances.display_id WHERE display_substances.substance_id = 1
```

I have read [How do I get the records from the left side of a join that do not exist in the joined table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11262636/how-do-i-get-the-records-from-the-left-side-of-a-join-that-do-not-exist-in-the-j)  but that didn't help.

### For further clarification

Let's say there are 120 rows in `display_substances` that correspond to substance ID 1 (`WHERE display_substances.substance_id = 1`). **The output of the query should always have 400 rows**. In this example, 120 should have `display_substances.value` next to them, and 280 should have the text "Not Listed".

Comment: Why are you using all these irregular integer types for ID fields? Just use `INT`. The number of bytes you save here are utterly irrelevant, and the amount of complexity you introduce just isn't worth it. MySQL has a `SERIAL` column type for auto-increment keys and it's `BIGINT` by default because it's 2018 and we really do not care about a byte here or a byte there. Terabyte-sized hard drives cost less than a nice pair of socks, bytes are cheap. Programmer time is expensive.

Comment: I appreciate your comment but it's of no use in solving the problem at hand. The column data types are irrelevant in as far as getting the output of the query to be correct, in this particular instance.

Comment: ahmad provided you an answer that will work assuming you don't hit the GROUP_CONCAT limitation.  Ramy's answer is also valuable and a possible solution.  The important part is the left outer join, which returns a row from the LEFT/initial table even if there are no joined rows in the right table.  With Ramy's example you just need to fetch through the results in a loop that keeps track of the current display, as you will have a row for each display/substance combination.  With that said, I would use pagination.

Comment: Pagination would only show one page of results at a time, and would be far more efficient.  Your current plan of generating a result set that will return over 1.5 million rows of data every time the page is generated is naive.  That is a lot of data  to read from the server to php and then from php to browser, each time the page is visited.  Most people would separate the search feature, and generate results as needed when search is employed rather than planning on using the browser and javascript.

Comment: If you are committed to trying to do this all in one giant page, then I would suggest caching using redis or memcache, and returning all your results in json format, so that your client javascript based searching features will be maintainable.

Comment: @gview you've misunderstood the bit about the table with 1.5 million rows. See the clarification I added to the original question (at the bottom). It should never return anything like that number, infact for any given substance the number of records it selects from this table must be <400 since `display_substances.display_id` must map to one of the 400 records in `displays`

Comment: @Andy: I had to re-read your response and the question a few times to finally see the disconnect here.  You omitted a very important piece of information in your question... that you have a substances table!  You need to add the schema of the substance table to the question.  This is why the queries have not worked as you expected.

Comment: @gview I don't think including a schema for that is helpful - it's not related to the question - other than there being a foreign key for it in `display_substances`. I've added that to the question.

Comment: @Andy, I've retracted my previous comment, but the clarification is that again this display is for one and only one substance at a time?  All your queries and all the responses omit this.

Comment: @gview Re-read point (2). The only relevance that the substance ID has is that the query needs to contain `WHERE displays_substances.substance_id = 1` (assuming the page is showing details of substance ID 1). The table showing the data in the application has 2 columns. Column 1 has to show all 400 rows from `displays`. Column 2 has to have anything from `display_substances` where the substance ID matches the one being shown by the page and that the `display_substances.display_id` matches `displays.id` for the current row. If there is no corresponding record it should say "Not listed".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a left join & a group_concat to get all records on the left table along with group by.

But keep in mind that group_concat has a limit so you might not get all associated records, as it's usually used for small fields but since you have a 'text' field for your value there's a high probability you'd hit the limit

Anyway here's the query

```
SELECT d.*, GROUP_CONCAT(ds.value) `substances`
FROM displays `d`
LEFT JOIN display_substances `ds` ON `d`.`id` = `ds`.`display_id`
GROUP BY `d`.`id`
```

Something like this might work then if I understand correctly

```
SELECT d.*, IFNULL((SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(value) FROM display_substances `ds` WHERE `ds`.`display_id` = `d`.`id` GROUP BY `ds`.`display_id`), 'Not Listed') `substances`
FROM displays `d`
```

You can update the where & add `AND substance_id = 1`

Comment: Thanks but I think you may have mis-understood the question. There should be a `WHERE` condition because I'm trying to do this per substance - i.e. it has to do `WHERE displays_substances.substance_id = 1`. Furthermore there is no condition in the SQL above to produce the text "Not Listed" if there is no corresponding row.

Comment: You'll get a null if there's nothing listed & you can add the where statement like any other query e.g: ``where `ds`.`substance_id` = 1``

Comment: oh wait, you don't need a where ... you're only supplying the id when using filters right? a where clause would not give you the 400 items. you need to add it to the join or use a subquery

Comment: I've added a clarification at the bottom of the question. Yes it should always output 400 rows.

Comment: I think a subquery would work for you, I have updated the answer

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is that you want the following:

- Your page limits the results by substance ID
- You want one substance per row
- If there are displays with no substances, they should still show in the page with "Not Listed" as the substance value

I believe this should work for you:

```
SELECT
    d.id AS display_id,
    d.label AS display_label,
    IFNULL(ds.value, 'Not Listed') AS substance_value
FROM displays AS d
LEFT JOIN display_substances AS ds ON (ds.display_id = d.id)
WHERE ds.substance_id = 1 OR ds.substance_id IS NULL;
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I believe it's going along the right lines but I've just tested it and it only gives me 120 rows. It should always return 400 rows. I can't see anything in the output of the query that says "Not Listed" for any row so I'm not sure if that part of the condition is working.

Comment: Just edited the answer, I forgot to account for NULL

Comment: I think you just need to move the substance_id =1 into Join condition.    Drop the WHERE clause.  `ON (ds.id = d.id AND ds.substance_id = 1)`

Answer (score 1):

I've realized that Ramy has about 98% of the solution.

FWIW this problem is just a variation on one that occurs all the time.

You will find other answers on SO when you [search for 'left outer join with where clause' -- that address the problem.  One example is this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17910729/mysql-left-outer-join-with-where-clause-return-unmatched-rows)

Ultimately, you have a many to many resolution table (display_substances) that resolves the many to many relationship between substances and displays.  You are just looking for an outer join from one of the 2 parent tables, but also requiring that you filter the results by a specific substance.

```
SELECT
    d.id AS display_id,
    d.label AS display_label,
    IFNULL(ds.value, 'Not Listed') AS substance_value
FROM displays AS d
LEFT JOIN display_substances AS ds ON (ds.display_id = d.id AND ds.substance_id = 1);
```

This query does not generate a value of 'not listed' but it does generate NULL columns for those display rows where there is no corresponding display_substance value.    You could embelish it with the IF_NULL() function demonstrated by ahmad, but as you are using PHP to go through the result set, you can just as easily handle that in the procedural loop you'll use to fetch the results.

Comment: Many thanks. I'm marking this as the correct answer - because it does what I asked. However, in my application, it's un-usable. I executed the above query and it took 160.19 seconds to run. The indexes have been set correctly. We can't use pagination because the app needs to show all 400 rows on 1 page. The PHP answer I posted takes approx 2 seconds to give the same output. To be fair I didn't ask about speed in my question, so your answer is "correct". We actually have Redis installed so in theory we could cache the HTML pages after the tables have been produced... but I won't be doing

Comment: @Andy:  I appreciate your willingness to evaluate the continued responses even if you decided to move on.  With that said, If you would be willing to use EXPLAIN on the query and update with the output, I am confident that the query can be tuned to return a response in a short amount of time.  I would not be surprised if it is subsecond, given that there is a small number of rows that should actually be returned.  If you want to create a new question for that endeavor, let me know.  Also FWIW, most of my development is also done with PHP, and I have no bias against using it for certain tasks.

Comment: In regards to Redis you would cache the data rather than the final HTML.  [HTML caching is best done using ESI](https://www.fastly.com/blog/using-esi-part-1-simple-edge-side-include) which is supported in various webservers and HTTP cache/reverse proxies like Varnish or Nginx with it's ESI module

Comment: thanks. The output of the `EXPLAIN` query is on a screenshot here: https://pasteboard.co/HK3QaCs.png

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting what I've used as a solution. I don't think it's possible to do this in MySQL as one query. Several people answered but none of the answers worked.

For even further clarification - although obvious from the question - the output in  the application is a table with 2 columns. The first of these columns should include all 400 rows from `displays`:

```
displays.label    |  display_substances.value
------------------|--------------------------
Display 1         
------------------|--------------------------
...
------------------|--------------------------
Display 400   
------------------|--------------------------
```

This is fairly trivial since at this point it's just `SELECT * FROM displays`.

The challenge begins when we want to populate the second column of the table with `display_substances.value`. The data for a given substance (assume substance ID is 1) might look like this:

```
id   |   display_id   |   substance_id  |  value
-----|----------------|-----------------|-------------
206  |      1         |        1            Foo
-----|----------------|-----------------|-------------
361  |      3         |        1            Bar
-----|----------------|-----------------|-------------
555  |      5         |        1            Baz
-----|----------------|-----------------|-------------
```

**The problem**: In this case we only have 3 records for substance ID 1. So if we do a `JOIN` query, it will only return 3 rows. But the table we are displaying in the application needs to show all 400 rows from `displays` and put the text "Not listed" on any row where there is no corresponding row in `display_substances`. So in the example above, when it encounters `display_id` 2, 4, 6...400 it should say "Not listed" (because we only have data for three `display_substances.display_id` [1,3,5] for substance ID 1).

Both columns also need to be searchable.

**My solution**

I don't think it's possible to do this in MySQL so I resorted to using PHP. The logic is as now follows:

1. If the user is doing a search on column 2 (`display_substances.value`): `SELECT display_id FROM display_substances WHERE value LIKE '% Search term column 2 %'`. Store this as an array, `$ds`.
2. Select all 400 records from `displays`. If the user is performing a search on column 1 (`displays.label`) then that must form part of the query: `SELECT * FROM displays WHERE label LIKE '% Search term column 1 %'`. Critically - if the `$ds` array from step (1) is not empty then the following must become part of query: `WHERE displays.id IN (2, 4, 6...400)`. Store this as an array, `$displays`
3. Get all of the `display_id's` associated with the substance being viewed: `SELECT display_id FROM display_substances WHERE substance_id = 1`
4. Do a loop as per *point (3) of the **original question***.

The result is that the page loads in <2 seconds, each column is searchable.

The SQL queries given in answers took - at best - around 15-20 seconds to execute and never gave all 400 rows.

If anyone can improve on this or has a pure SQL solution please post.

Comment: It is possible to do it in MySQL only.  If it is taking a long time that is because you are likely missing an index you would need.  Once the query works you use EXPLAIN query to determine the strategy mysql is using.